# Encoding Error in R command line but not in RStudio

Tags: r, csv, encoding

I'm using a Windows 7 machine with R 3.0.0 installed trying to run a script I've written through the R command line.

The script takes in a .csv file (created using Save As... in Excel in MS-DOS and UTF-8 format) and applies a number of Dplyr functions to it before writing the results to csv.

The script works wonderfully in R using the following line to read in the data:

```
data <- read.csv(fileName, fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

However it fails at this line in the command prompt with the following warnings which i believe indicate the file was not actually read:

```
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, :
invalid input found on input connection 'C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-33~1.3\bin\x64\RTerm.exe'

2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, :
invalid final line found by readTableHeader 'C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-33~1.3\bin\x64\RTerm.exe'
```

For the record I'm using the following format in the command line:

```
RScript MyRFile.R --args arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated

Comment: I have the same problem. Any news on this?